# Need to send data to server via javascript in json format

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am having trouble posting my data from a form to the server but must be in json format and using ajax. How do I do this while using javascript & **cannot use Jquery**. **Here my questions...**

Also Thanks in Advance!

- How do I convert it and send it to the server with handling HTTP 200 success and using ajax?
- On return of a JSON
  object with the status encoded like so: {"status":"---"}, where "---" is either "success" or "error".
- If the response status is success, a thank you message should be
  displayed.
- If the response status is error, the page should display a general
  warning such as 'request could not be completed'.

  **HTML**

  Contact Me

  ```
  <form id="contactus" action="http://wirehoer.net" method="post">
  <fieldset>
      <!-- Contact Name
       -->
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input name="name" id="name" type="text" pattern="\b[-'a-zA-Z]+,?\s[-'a-zA-Z]{0,19}\b" autofocus required>
      <span id="name-error" class="error">Please enter first & last name</span>
      <!-- Email 
      -->
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="email" pattern="^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$" required>
      <span id="email-error" class="error">Please enter email address</span>
      <!-- Phone 
      -->
      <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
      <input name="phone" id="phone" type="tel" pattern="\d{10}" required>
      <span id="phone-error" class="error">Phone number must only contain numbers</span>
      <!-- Status - Client | Partner | Vendor 
      -->
      <label for="status">Status:         
          <select name="status" id="status">
              <option value="client">Client</option>
              <option value="partner">Partner</option>
              <option value="vendor">Vendor</option>
          </select>
      </label>
      <!-- Subscribe 
      -->
      <label for="subscribe">
      <input name="newsletter" id="subscribe" type="checkbox" value="on" checked>
          Send me your newsletter</label>
      <!-- Support - Sales | Support 
      -->
      <label class="needs" for="select_sales">
          <input id="select_sales" name="slsSelect" type="radio" value="sales" checked>Sales
      </label>
      <label class="needs" for="select_support">      
          <input id="select_support" name="slsSelect" type="radio" value="support">Support
      </label>
      <!-- Description 
      -->
      <label for="details">Message:</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="details" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
      <span id="details-error" class="error">Please describe what your request is</span>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
      <button id= "send" type="submit">Send</button>
      <button type="reset">Reset</button>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
  <!-- javascript validation 
  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="contactform_Lab11.js"></script>

  </body>
  </html>
  ```

**Javascript**

```
> //This will get the data of the fields
> document.getElementById('send').onclick=function(evt) {
> 
> var errors = false; //Gets all the inputs from contact form var
> myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select');
> 
> //Declar the vars //var i, val; // empty Array
> 
> //Start of loop  for (i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {
>     // Get element
>     val = myNodeList[i];
> 
>     //Get pattern attribute of regEx
>     regEx = new RegExp(val.getAttribute("pattern"));
> 
>     //Get Error message
>     err = document.getElementById(val.id+"-error")
> 
>     //By default, set the class to error, which hides the error message
>             err.className="error";
> 
>     //Test value "val" again the regEx
>     if(!regEx.test(val.value)){
>         //input fails and does not pass regEx test, set .display class
>         err.className+=" display";
> 
>         errors = true;
>     } } evt.preventDefault(); if(errors ===false){
>     document.getElementById("contactus").submit(); } };
```

Comment: You've basically just listed your project requirements rather than asked a specific, code-based question. I'd suggest trimming your question down to a specific one, including only code that is pertinent to that question. You can always ask multiple questions if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set all the data you need in an object, and send it as a JSON string in an AJAX request.

```
  document.getElementById('send').onclick = function (evt) {

        var errors = false; //Gets all the inputs from contact form var
        myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select');
        var data = {};
        //Declar the vars //var i, val; // empty Array

        //Start of loop  
        for (i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {
            // Get element
            val = myNodeList[i].value;
            data[myNodeList[i].id] = val;
            //Get pattern attribute of regEx
            regEx = new RegExp(val.getAttribute("pattern"));

            //Get Error message
            err = document.getElementById(val.id + "-error")

            //By default, set the class to error, which hides the error message
            err.className = "error";

            //Test value "val" again the regEx
            if (!regEx.test(val.value)) {
                //input fails and does not pass regEx test, set .display class
                err.className += " display";

                errors = true;
            }
        }

        evt.preventDefault();
        if (errors === false) {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

            req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            req.open('POST', 'http://wirehopper.net/ajax-submit.php');
            req.onload = function () {
                if(req.status == 200)
                    alert(req.response);
            }
            //TODO: implement error handling
            req.send(JSON.stringify(data));

        };
    }
```

Comment: Don't I need  XMLHttpRequest(); @Carlouuus

Comment: Yes, the ajax call is using the XMLHttpRequest object

`var req = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: How does this come into play   req.setRequestHeader  ? @Carlouuus

Comment: While @Carlouuus has answered this question perfectly, if you're not a fan of XMLHttpRequest (and frankly, who is... I mean, just look at that camelcasing) then I'd recommend looking at some micro frameworks  to help you out. Just found this http://microjs.com/#AJAX which shows how popular certain frameworks are. [Pegasus](https://github.com/typicode/pegasus) looks really good for AJAX. If you're going to do a lot more than just a bit of AJAX, then something more substantial, such as [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), might be in order.